# Radio button observable value is not changing in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I have a object `Address`. In address there are fields like `street`, `country`,`state`,`IsDefault`. The addresses can be multiple and IsDefault will be radio
button.

```
   $.each(self.Addresses(), function (index, address) {  
        address.Street = ko.observable(adderss.Street);         
        address.State = ko.observable(address.State);
        address.Country = ko.observable(address.Country);
        address.IsDefault = ko.observable(address.IsDefault.toString());
        address.IsGlobalCheckbox = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return address.IsDefault() + "";
            },
            write: function (v) {                   
                if (v == "true") {
                    address.IsDefault(true)
                }
                else {
                    address.IsDefault(false)
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The Html content will be

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: Addresses">
<div>
    Address <span data-bind="text: ($index() + 1)" class="mrl"></span>


    <input name="contactAddress" type="radio" data-bind="checked:IsGlobalCheckbox,attr: { value:IsDefault }" />

    <span>Primary</span>



<div data-bind="attr:{id:'address'+($index() + 1)}" class="in">
    <div class="row">            
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Street 1</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Street" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>           
        <div class="form-group medium">
            <label >Country</label>
            <input data-bind="value:Country" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group medium">
            <label>State</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value:State" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i am changing one default address then it is changing, but remaining is default observables are not changing. Hope you understand my question.

I am attaching a fiddle explaining my requirement in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Naidu526/fzX8C/2/

In that fiddle when i am changing the IsDefault from one field to another field the other observable value is not changing. Please check the json format that is displayed below

Comment: Alas, your question is not really clear. You can do several things to make it more answerable. First up, make sure to format your code for readability. Second, make sure the code you post is actually a [repro](http://sscce.org) (something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fzX8C/), only then an actual repro). This will also help you catch typos in your code (you have "adders" there...). Make sure the repro contains as little code as possible/needed to understand the problem. Finally, it helps in understanding the question if you tell us what you've tried. Good luck!

Comment: @Jeroen I have updated my question and added the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are never clearing/falsifying the state from the previously selected `Address` nor do you have access to that value.

Using and duplicating (see `IsGlobalCheckbox`) the value of `IsDefault` within each `Address` doesn't make much sense. If only 1 can be selected and that state is to be communicated to all others, then that context belongs above/outside of the `Address` model. Even the current naming indicates it doesn't belong there.

So, define a new observable in `$root`/`$parent` depending on the overall structure of the production model to store the `Primary Address`.

```
 self.primaryAddress = ko.observable();
```

Change the html binding to use the `checkValue` parameter of the `checked` binding so that the actual `Address` is stored in the model.

```
 <input name="contactAddress" type="radio" data-bind="checked:$root.primaryAddress, checkedValue: $data" /> <span>Primary</span>
```

Now we have the proper setup to "listen" for changes and modify `IsDefault` accordingly.

Two options are available:

1. Manage the value manually via 2 subscriptions on `primaryAddress`
2. Turn `IsDefault` into a computed observable with a dependency on `primaryAddress`

I like option #2.

```
address.IsDefault = ko.computed(function(){
  return address === self.primaryAddress()
});
```

Just be sure to include the initialization:

```
 if(address.IsDefault == "true"){          
   self.primaryAddress(address)
 }
```

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/qkECp/) for the full setup. I have also included Option #1 in commented-out code just as a reference.